# How to force user to fill name while sign-up (devise)? [Rails 6]

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, devise, rubygems

I have a problem with one of my first projects with Rails 6, I'm a newcomer and tried to deal with it for some days but nothing is working. **I want to force an user to fill First name and Last name while sign-ing up**. Previously I had set the name to display to Anonymous if someone doesn't provide names. It works for old users on my local acc but **new user can sign-up and the name field is blank, why?** I had set up that if there is no first or last name it should be anonymous...

I have used **devise gem for authentication** to make a sign-up page with email and password that have to be filled. Then later I added two extra fields on my sign-up page for first name and last name by running:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
    end
end
```

**added views**

```
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <%= f.label :first_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'first_name', class: 'form-control' %>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <%= f.label :last_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'last_name', class: 'form-control' %>
   </div>

</div>
```

I have added migration and run **db:migrate**

```
  def change
    add_column :users, :first_name, :string
    add_column :users, :last_name, :string
  end
```

Before I had this model to display full name in navigation bar:

```
def full_name
  return "#{first_name} #{last_name}" if first_name || last_name
  "Anonymous"
end

<li class='nav-item user-name'>
  <%= fa_icon 'user' %> <%= current_user.full_name %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add validation in the user model that validates the presence of firstname and lastname.

```rb
# models/user.rb
validates_presence_of :firstname, :lastname
```